# How am I supposed to add music to my WP8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

With my WP7 there was Zune.  Zune is great, you can use it to sync whatever you want to the phone from your PC.  Now, I got this WP8, a Nokia 521, and it is a nice phone. I can expand  the memory to as much as 64 GB, and tell the phone I want all new music to go onto the expansion SD card.  I put a 32 GB SD card in there.

Except that I don't see how you're supposed to actually put the music onto the phone!  I have put music on it, but it doesn't play like it has been added correctly.  It takes several seconds to even start playing, and some of the albums won't play at all.  Sometimes they play, but pause intermittently.

I can move the MP3's to the phone, and even put them in the Music folder, but is this the way to actually add music correctly?  Maybe I have a bad phone?

Answer (score 1):

You can either download the Windows Phone app from the store and add music via that (there should be a button near the phone tile on the left or just add it directly into the music folder on the device view in explorer (like a flash drive).

Comment: Download the Windows Phone app?  The phone has a marketplace app already.  It's built in.  Or are you talking about a different app?  I've tried adding music directly to the folder, but it doesn't seem to work well.

Comment: OK, I found a Windows Phone app in the Windows store.  Unfortunately it requires Windows 8.  I'm still stuck in Vista.

Comment: Then you will have to use the device as a flash drive. Shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Windows Phone App for Desktop supports Win7: http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/how-to/wp8/windows-phone-app-for-desktop